# How can I find a faster algorithm for this special case of Longest Common Sub-sequence (LCS)?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dynamic-programming, lcs

I know the LCS problem need time ~ O(m*n) where m and n are length of two sequence X and Y respectively. But my problem is a little bit easier so I expect a faster algorithm than ~O(m*n).

Here is my problem:

Input:

a positive integer Q, two sequence X=x1,x2,x3.....xn and Y=y1,y2,y3...yn, both of length n.

Output:

True, if the length of the LCS of X and Y is at least  n - Q;

False, otherwise.

The well-known algorithm costs O(n^2) here, but actually we can do better than that. Because whenever we eliminate as many as Q elements in either sequence without finding a common element, the result returns False. Someone said there should be an algorithm as good as O(Q*n), but I cannot figure out.

UPDATE:
Already found an answer!

I was told I can just calculate the diagonal block of the table c[i,j], because if |i-j|>Q, means there are already more than Q unmatched elements in both sequences. So we only need to calculate the c[i,j] when |i-j|<=Q.

Comment: So in essence you just need to find a common subsequence of length n-Q, and so we know that it must start in one of the first Q+1 positions. That's bound to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to do it:
1. Let's assume that `f(prefix_len, deleted_cnt)` is the leftmost position in `Y` such that `prefix_len` elements of `X` were already processed and exactly `deleted_cnt` of them were deleted. Obviously, there are only `O(N * Q)` states because `deleted_cnt` cannot exceed `Q`.
2. The base case is `f(0, 0) = 0`(nothing was processed, thus nothing was deleted).
3. Transitions:
a) Remove the current element: `f(i + 1, j + 1) = min(f(i + 1, j + 1), f(i, j))`.
b) Match the current element with the leftmost possible element from `Y` that is equal to it and located after `f(i, j)`(let's assume that it has index `pos`): `f(i + 1, j) = min(f(i + 1, j), pos)`.
4. So the only question remaining is how to get the leftmost matching element located to the right from a given position. Let's precompute the following pairs: (position in `Y`, element of `X`) -> the leftmost occurrence of the element of `Y` equal to this element of `X` to the right from this position in `Y` and put them into a hash table. It looks like `O(n^2)`. But is not. For a fixed position in `Y`, we never need to go further to the right from it than by `Q + 1` positions. Why? If we go further, we skip more than `Q` elements! So we can use this fact to examine only `O(N * Q)` pairs and get desired time complexity. When we have this hash table, finding `pos` during the step 3 is just one hash table lookup. Here is a pseudo code for this step:

```
map = EmptyHashMap()
for i = 0 ... n - 1:
    for j = i + 1 ... min(n - 1, i + q + 1)
        map[(i, Y[j])] = min(map[(i, Y[j])], j)
```

Unfortunately, this solution uses hash tables so it has `O(N * Q)` time complexity on average, not in the worst case, but it should be feasible.

Comment: Thanks! this method is great. However, I was told I can just calculate the diagonal block of the table c[i,j], because if |i-j|>Q, means there are already more than Q unmatched elements in both sequences. So we only need to calculate the c[i,j] when |i-j|<=Q.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Oh, yeah. It is really simple! My solution looks like an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say cost of the process to make the string equal must not be greater than Q.if it greater than Q than answer must be false.(EDIT DISTANCE PROBLEM)

Suppose of the of string x is m, and the size of string y is n, then we create a two dimensional array d[0..m][0..n], where d[i][j] denotes the edit distance between the i-length prefix of x and j-length prefix of y.

The computation of array d is done using dynamic programming, which uses the following recurrence:

```
d[i][0] = i , for i <= m
d[0][j] = j , for j <= n

d[i][j] = d[i - 1][j - 1], if s[i] == w[j],
d[i][j] = min(d[i - 1][j] + 1, d[i][j - 1] + 1, d[i - 1][j - 1] + 1), otherwise.
```

answer of LCS  `if m>n, m-dp[m][m-n]`